# keycode for device home button in javascript or android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

i need the keycode for device home button in android or javascript to separate my code.Please guide me to solve this issue.

Here is my sample code i have tried.But this is not working.

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent keyevent) {
    Log.i("keyevent","button click ");
    if (keyevent.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME) {
        //Do here what you want
        Log.i("keyevent","home button click");
        return true;
    }
    else
        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(keyevent);
```

}

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can not control the behaviour of Home key .

You can monitor the life cycle of activity. When the home button is pressed following sequence of methods is called:

```
onPause()
onStop()
onRestart()
onStart()
onResume()
```